# Regular expression for multiple matches between curly brackets

Tags: swift, regex

The server is sending a string that will have the key inside it. one string can have multiple key. I need to write a regular expression to extract the key.
For example, if string coming from the server is

```
"{{call_started}} at 6.50 but the user was not available. {{
user_name}} must be offline. "
```

Here we have two key: call_started and user_name

in the incoming string, all key will start with `{{` and end with `}}`.

How to write the regular expression for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below regex:

```
\{\{(.*?)\}\}
```

By using above, Mactch 1 Group 1 will have `call_started` and Match 2 Group 1 will have `user_name`

This will match all the occurrences of `{{ }}`

See usage and explanation here https://regex101.com/r/CESeIy/1

Comment: When I m trying to create NSReguralExpression it is returning nil

Comment: NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\{{(.*?)\\}}", options: .caseInsensitive) returning nil

Comment: @AashishNagar try using the updated expression above. I have escaped all the curly brackets by using "\"